# Retrive value list of Decimal Type without class name

Tags: django, list, decimal, django-queryset

when I run this query in django:

```
list(InputDataDetailItem.objects.filter(wage_detail__wage=wage).values_list('value',flat=True))
```

I get :

```
[Decimal('30.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00')]
```

but I want :

```
[30.00,0.00,0.00]
```

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is (likely) a [**DecimalField** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField). You can convert these by calling `float` on them:

```
[   float(x)
    for x in InputDataDetailItem.objects.filter(
        wage_detail__wage=wage
    ).values_list('value',flat=True)]
```

Note that since a `Decimal` encodes digits, whereas a float encodes binary, there might be (small) rounding errors.